# How to use Overcommit inside of Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, rubygems, rbenv, ruby-overcommit

I have installed "Overcommit" globally using:

```
sudo gem install overcommit
```

It works inside of terminal, but when I try to commit code from within Xcode, I get the following error:

> This repository contains hooks installed by Overcommit, but the `overcommit` gem is not installed.
>   Install it with `gem install overcommit`.

My `overcommit.yml` file looks like this:

```
PreCommit:
  SwiftLint:
    enabled: true
    command: ["Pods/SwiftLint/swiftlint", "lint", "--strict"]
```

It is also worth noting that I installed Ruby using `rbenv` and set the newest version as my global version.

Is there any way to make it work from inside Xcode?

Comment: you should not have to install gems using `sudo` this generally indicates an issue with your environment set up

Comment: I installed it without using sudo on my other machine, but still got the same error